# Undefined c++ variable of struct array

Tags: c++, variables

I have the following method in a file called index.cpp.  When I compile, it's telling me that "indexStructure" is not defined in this scope.

```
#include "index.h"
#include <cctype> // provides isalpha() and tolower()
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

void index::shiftRight (int i)
{
if ( indexSize == (sizeof(indexStructure) / sizeof(indexStructre[0])))
    doubleIndex();

for (int j = indexSize; j > i; j--)
    indexStructure [j] = indexStructure [j-1];
}
```

in index.h, i have

```
class index
{

struct node {
    string item;
    int counter;
    int* pageNumber;
};

...

private:
    node* indexStructure;
    int lineCounter;
    int indexSize;

};
```

I intend to make an array of type node and use it to search through words in a book.  Why is it undefined?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You misspelled `sizeof(indexStructre[0])` in  `index::shiftRight()`. Correct that to `indexStructure` and try again.

Answer (score 2):

`indexStructre` Here letter `u` is missing after letter `t`. However, you are spelling it correctly while you said about compiler is complaining :)